# Why is Visual studio referencing the wrong row during exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

Some simple rows of code below:

```
string[] countries = new string[1];
string[] cities = new string[1];

countries[0] = "USA";
countries[1] = "England";
cities[0] = "Chicago";
```

When Visual Studio throws the null exception it references the following row and not the row where the exception occurred:
[image]

I know the line number is correct when you view details of the problem. However, I often spend more time than necessary searching the wrong variables because the visual representation of the exception was wrong.

Is it possible to tweak VS or do something else to solve this issue? Is it a known problem or is it just me?

Comment: What version of VS2010 are you using? When I ran your code, the IndexOutOfRangeException highlight was on `countries[1] = "England";` -- I have VS2010 10.0.30319.341 and .NET 4.0.30319.

Comment: I sometimes see this happen if I modify the code while I am running it. why not put the code in a try/catch block and put a breakpoint on some code in the catch block.

Comment: `VS2010 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel` and `.NET 4.0.30319`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is apparently a [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641947/exception-assistant-highlights-incorrect-line-of-code).

Comment: Oh, there you go. Maybe it's being fixed then =)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the bug @CodeNaked referenced is what you are experiencing. I know that I have gotten this a lot when debugging code that has changed and needs to be recompiled. I would try a clean and rebuild.

Comment: If I create a new project (ASP.NET Web Application) and put this code in the page_load() function of Default.aspx I still get this error. Or did you mean something else with a clean build?

Comment: That's very interesting. I actually meant in your current application to go to the build menu and click "Clean", but if you are getting it on a brand new project, then I doubt that will do any good. Sorry I can't be of more assistance.